# How can I get desired results(displaying list of courses) when I run Angular 2 typescript?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 2. I am trying a small program to display list of courses.The desired output is

My first Angular App

Display courses

this is title of courses

. Maths

. Science

. English

The output displayed on chrome is attached as below.
[image: output]
I would be great if anyone can help point what's wrong in the program and how can I get the desired result.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

    @Component({
        selector: 'courses',
        template: `
        <h2> Display courses</h2>
        {{title}}
        <ul>
           <li *ngFor="#c of coursesName">
           {{coursesName}}
           </li>
        </ul>
        `

    })
    export class CoursesComponent{
        title:string="this is title of courses";
        coursesName = ["Maths", "Science", "English"];
    }
```

Comment: use `*ngFor="let  c of couseName"` instead of `#c`

Comment: @prajeeshkumar If OP is using an earlier version of angular2 (before beta.17) your comment won't work as I've noted in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
 <li *ngFor="#c of coursesName">
    {{coursesName}}
 </li>
```

Should be

```
 <li *ngFor="#c of coursesName">
    {{c}}
 </li>
```

`c` is the nth element of `coursesName`, `coursesName` is the whole array

**Note**: with beta.17 `<div *ngFor="#c of coursesName">` became `<div *ngFor="let c of coursesName">`

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta17-2016-04-28

Comment: Thank you @echonax. Got the desired output.

Comment: @prajeeshkumar in beta it was with `#` so I thought OP might be using the beta version, https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta17-2016-04-28

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the binding incorrectly, please make sure to [review the documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html)

When you do `*ngFor="let course of courses"` you need to use the `course` declaration for your bindings.

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let course of courses">
   {{courses}}
   </li>
</ul>
export class CoursesComponent{
    title:string="this is title of courses";
    courses= ["Maths", "Science", "English"];
}
```